# how to create a duplicate data extension from a synchronized DE without manually typing all fields for the new DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm trying to create a new DE from an existing synchronized DE with all the fields prepopulated. When I create the DE I want it to copy all the fields and field types for the synchronized DE to the new DE without me having to either manually typing them or using the SOAP API. 
I tried creating a filter from the synchronized DE but that will not solve my issue. I need it to be specifically a "standard" DE rather than a filter. 
Is this by any chance possible at this moment?

Answer (score 4):

If you are not willing to type it manually or use SOAP API, there is another way to go: using **Deployment Manager**.

> Use Deployment Manager to copy the design of a journey or **data
>   extension** and **deploy it** to **other Marketing Cloud business units** or
>   enterprises. You can then configure the new draft journey or data
>   extension design in the target account. Deployment Manager doesn’t
>   store or migrate any customer or campaign data.

Steps to follow:

1- Install the Deployment Manager on your BU --> [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_set_up_deployment_manager.htm&type=5)

2- Create a Snapshot of your DE and download it --> [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_create_snapshot.htm&type=5)

3- Deploy the Snapshot on the same BU --> [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_deploy_to_another_account.htm&type=5)

I've tested creating a Filtred DE, create a Snapshot and deploy it. It actually deploys a **Standard DE** instead of filtered DE which responds to your use case.

Hope this helps

Comment: Good find using deployment manager

Comment: @rachidmamai I don't see an option to select from Synchronized Data Extensions under component types. I only see "Journeys", "Data Extensions", 'Shared Data Extensions

Comment: Thanks EasyE. @NinoY You can use your filtered DE created from your Synchronized DE and then create a Snapshot > Deploy the filtered DE..

Comment: @RachidMamai seems like its a bit glitchy. We have a lot of DEs so I have to search for the new one and it seems like the search bar doesnt work or something. unfortunately, I wasn't able to achieve my goal with it.